# GPO not applying to user

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I'm testing setting user printers via group policy and I'm running into a strange issue.

I created a new OU and then another sub OU. I then created a new blank GPO called IT as you can see in the following picture:

[image: GP]

I then moved my user account to the IT OU. The test desktop I am logging into is under the Desktops OU. When I log into the computer and run a gpresult I can see the default domain policy and the desktop GP applied but not the IT GPO.

If I move the computer to the IT OU then it will pick up the GPO. But if only my user account is in there it doesn't get applied.

Guessing I'm missing something very simple here, but so far I haven't been able to figure it out. This is the first time I've tried applying a GPO directly to a user. Usually we just apply to a computer and loopback process for the users.

Comment: Are you setting Computer Configuration settings or User Configuration settings in the GPO?

Comment: Loopback won't help you here, loopback processing means user policies that touch a computer object are applied to all users who log into that computer; not the other way around. Are you trying to apply a GP Preference (Computer Configuration | Preferences | Control Panel Settings | Printers)?

Comment: I first set it up as a User Config, tested a Computer config later. Yeah I figured Loopback wouldn't do anything, so I hadn't even bothered with it at first. I'm trying to set User, Policies, Windows Settings, Printer Connections(Deployed Printers).

Comment: Run the Group Policy Results wizard from the GPMC for your computer and user and see why the GPO in question isn't being applied.

Comment: Ok, so, I think I found the real problem, but I'm not sure of the solution. The Desktop GP object is overwriting the IT one. The IT should apply to the user account and if the computer isn't in the Desktops OU it works. But after moving to Desktops OU the Desktop GP overwrites the IT User config and it doesn't even show up as a denied GPO...

Comment: Have you double checked the Desktops GPO to see if Loopback Policy Processing is enabled? It sounds like it's enabled in Replace mode.

Comment: Hmm okay. You are most likely right. Changing to merge mode should be fine I would guess.

Comment: Yep, that was it. So I was right, it was something stupidly easy. @joeqwerty if you want to convert your comment into a answer I will mark it as such. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you double checked the Desktops GPO to see if Loopback Policy Processing is enabled? It sounds like it's enabled in Replace mode. If that's the case then the user settings in your IT GPO are being replaced by the user settings in your Desktop GPO.